# Когда стала использоваться фраза "извините за банальность"?

Tags: фразеология

Это ведь довольно необычная вещь - просить прощения за простоту сказанной мысли. Когда впервые стала употребляться эта фраза и во всех ли социальных слоях она используется? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ: БАНАЛЬНЫЙ,  [франц. banal]. Заурядный, хорошо известный, неоригинальный.  Говорить банальные слова.

Вы можем сказать:  «История сослагательного наклонения не имеет» или «Связь времен распалась» и  попросить извинение за банальность, так как  эти утверждения общеизвестны, неоригинальны и предположительно не несут в себе новой информации  для вашего  собеседника.

Но тогда зачем банальные слова  употребляются в речи? Чаще всего это афоризмы, крылатые выражения, которые применяются к конкретной ситуации и служат для её лучшего понимания, а также делают речь яркой, эмоциональной или, может быть,  представляют вас образованным человеком, с этим афоризмами знакомым.

В русском языке слово банальный известно с середины 19 века, в словарях с 1861 года, хотя слово «банальность»  встречается уже  в повести Толстого  «Юность» 1855-56.  Происхождение у слова интересное: оно заимствовано из фр. языка  с тем же значением, которое отмечается там  с 18 века.  Ст.-фр. слово banal происходит от нем. ban -  приказ, объявление, несущее угрозу, и тогда  banal –  это относящийся к приказу сюзерена, к  общей повинности, к баналитету, к тому, что обязаны делать все. И уже потом слово «банальный» начинает обозначать всё неоригинальное, общепринятое и общеизвестное. 
http://clubs.ya.ru/4611686018427453093/replies.xml?item_no=667

Синонимом слова банальный является тривиальный, заимствованное в первой половине XIX в. из франц. яз., где trivial < лат. trivialis "избитый, обычный".  Так, Достоевский в романе  «Братья Карамазовы» (1880) писал: «Простите за тривиальность выражения, но я в жару, я в горячке…».

В современной речи выражение "извините за банальность" употребляется часто, разными людьми и по самым разным поводам (от житейских проблем до философских рассуждений). Даже стихи пишут, например: "Прости за банальность!Я соткан из них, Как глупая крайность Заумной возни" (В. Верхонин).  Даже посвящают этому высказыванию статьи, например: "Пожалуй, трудно найти человека, который хоть когда-то не произнес эту банальную, то есть лишенную новизны или оригинальности, фразу. Что ж, я тоже не исключение и т.д.".
http://dr-o-cilla.livejournal.com/11776.html

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу только на вторую часть вопроса. Общался и с профессорами (да и с простыми преподавателями) университета,  и с юристами, и с чиновниками (регионального уровня, разумеется), и с полицейскими, и с интеллигенцией (в общем смысле слова), и с врачами, и с представителями сферы торговли (предпринимателями, маркетологами, экономистами, прочее и прочее), и с отставными военными, и с "дворовыми пацанами", и с криминалитетом, иными словами - почти со всеми прослойками общества.
**НИКТО** не извиняется за банальность. Видимо, не считают это зазорным. Что ещё тут добавишь?